# Python to connect to 2 different SSH sessions using multithreading

Tags: python

I am using pexpect to peform ssh operations on 2 servers. The idea behind is , i will ssh to first ssh server, then in another separate thread ssh to second ssh server. I will run some commands on the 2nd SSH server and capture the output in 1st SSH server.

The code is working fine, except for the fact that , the 1st SSH server session terminates in between before receiving all the commands from the 2nd ssh server.

I do not want to use interact() as i am performing an automation.

```
class THREAD_CLASS(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, object):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.obj = object

    def run(self):
        self.obj.run()

class someClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.child = pexpect.spawn('ssh '+ MACHINE_IP, logfile=self.logfile)
        i = self.child.expect(['(yes/no)', 'Password:'])
        if i == 0:
            self.child.sendline('yes')
            self.child.expect('password:')
            self.child.sendline('passwd')
        elif i == 1:
            self.child.sendline('passwd')
        self.child.expect('shell password')
        self.child.sendline('cmd1')
        self.child.expect('#')
        self.child.sendline('cmd2')
        self.child.expect('#')
        self.child.sendline('cmd3')
        self.child.expect('>')
        #self.child.sendline('cmd4')
        #self.child.expect('>')
        #self.child.sendline('cmd5')
        #self.child.expect('>')
        self.child.sendline('cmd6')
        self.child.expect('>')
        self.child.sendline('cmd7')
        self.child.expect('>')
        self.child.sendcontrol('m')
        self.child.sendline('cmd8')
        self.child.expect('>')
        self.child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=60)
        #self.child.sendline('exit')
        #self.child.expect('#')
        #self.child.sendcontrol('m')
        #self.child.expect('#')
        #self.child.sendline('exit')
        #self.child.interact()

    def stop(self):
        return 1


class secondClass():
    # some code here
    pass


# Threaded module
firstclass = BASE_THREAD(someClass)
secondclass = BASE_THREAD(secondClass)
```

if you see it, i am running both the ssh class in a 2 different threads.

The program works fine to an extent, When i am running the commands in secondClass, i am able to log the data to the log files. But the problem is, i am not getting the logs completely. At some point of time, the first thread terminates.

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Also, i want to run a series of command, once all the commands in the second SSH session gets done. Is it possible ?

Thanks,.